# How to build an HTML grid from the controller values using HTML controls in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, html, html5, slds

So I am using the SLDS and it uses all HTML5 syntax.  I'm curious how to build a table/grid using a controller.  I am trying using a static reference inside the  control.

I figured I'd create a string based on SOQL and then pass that to the visualforce page to render.  However, it's showing the code in the static reference.

Curious if I have to re-render.  all the examples in the SLDS documentation hard code values.  In .NET I'd use Razor syntax.  You can see below that it's not putting the static reference in between the table

[image: static reference in wrong spot]

**Visualforce:**

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" style="margin-bottom: 30px">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
               {!test}
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" data-label="Opportunity Name" title="Cloudhub">
                <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Cloudhub</a></div>
              </th>
              <td data-label="Account Name" title="Cloudhub">
                <div class="slds-truncate">Cloudhub</div>
              </td>  
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Apex:**

```
public string getTest(){
        return '<th scope="col" title="Opportunity Name"> ' + 
                '    <div class="slds-truncate">Opportunity Name</div>' +
                '</th>' +
                '<th scope="col" title="Account Name">' +
                '    <div class="slds-truncate">Account Name</div>' +
                '</th>';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html test to:

```
<table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" style="margin-bottom: 30px">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
               <apex:outputtext escape="false">{!test}</apex:outputtext>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" data-label="Opportunity Name" title="Cloudhub">
                <div class="slds-truncate"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Cloudhub</a></div>
              </th>
              <td data-label="Account Name" title="Cloudhub">
                <div class="slds-truncate">Cloudhub</div>
              </td>  
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[`<apex:outputText>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) can do this for you.

Also, i would recommend to go through "[`<apex:repeat/>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm)" and "[`<apex:dataTable/>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) tags. They work like `for` loop.

Try this:

```
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header" >
                    <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-text-heading--label">field1</apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!data.field1__c}" styleClass="slds-truncate" />
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:outputLabel styleClass="slds-text-heading--label">Field 2</apex:outputLabel>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!data.Activity_Time_Stamp__c}" styleClass="slds-truncate" />
            </apex:column>        
        </apex:dataTable>
```

Comment: I tried the <apex:OutputText escape="false"> and I'm still having issues.  For some reason the escape is not working.

Comment: also, I tried with datatable and couldn't get the styling to work

Comment: Also, I updated to include a pic of how it is rendering.

Comment: even adding the entire table to the apex controller it's still not rendering in the browser, despite having escape = false

Comment: I'm going to try the datatable and repeat

Comment: it kinda works. However, I cannot get the styleClass to work with the Facet column header

Comment: @tjcinnamon please post the updated code

Comment: I ended up getting it.  I had StyleClasses in my column which was overriding my OutputText for the row data.  I was using OutputText for my column where I needed an OutputLabel in order to use the slds-text-heading--label CSS class.  May I edit your post to include the answer using the data table and then mark it?

Comment: Sure. You can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Add some unique id to the tr as below

```
<tr id="test-headings-id" class="slds-text-heading--label"> </tr>
```

At the end of page, in the script section add line,

```
document.getElementById("test-headings-id").innerHtml = '{!test}';
```

Comment: dang, that didn't work either